# Android Countdown timer one after other

Tags: android

I want start countdown timer one after other in android application.I am facing this problem I have written a code of second countdown timer's onFinish() method and it should start second timer.

Comment: show your code, it will be helpful to catch issue

Comment: please see this link I have posted my quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877126/nesting-countdown-timers-in-android

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question again,instead wait for answers or the best way I would suggest you is Go to particular [**chat room**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and ask to experts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyActivity {

private class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {
   void onFinish() {
       mTimer.start();
   }
}

private mTimer = new MyTimer();

void firstStart() {
    mTimer.start();
}
}
```

But this way there will be a lot of MyTimer objects created/destroyed. Consider using [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead. Or a [ScheduledExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex but My problem is I want to do both show a progressbar and run timer if u want to see my code I have posted it as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877126/nesting-countdown-timers-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you can use Android message handler, which allows you to send messages with delay, this delay can be your countdown.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

use

```
sendMessageDelayed(Message msg, long delayMillis)
```

to send a delayed message.

here's and example to how to use Handlers: [Android message Handler Example](http://idlesun.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/android-handler-and-message-tutorial.html)